# Modular assets smoothing problem

Tags: edges, asset

I'm creating modular assets for a game (Unity). My problem is, that the smoothing is not being applied to the edges between the assets. I did create this example single wall.

[image: single modular asset]

Now I want to tile the asset, so I can create a longer wall. But the smoothing is not being applied to the edges between the wall assets.

[image: tiled assets with selection]

[image: tiled assets]

Technically I could create the environment within Blender and export the whole environment to Unity. In Blender I could merge the assets (edges) and fix the smoothing like this:

[image: tiled assets merged in Blender]

Is there another way to fix the smoothing? So I can still export single modular assets to Unity and not merge them in Blender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did find a way how to solve it. I used this merged wall (Straight.001):

[image]

And used a modifier on my main single asset (Straight) like this:

[image]

Further explanation can be found here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=99zHzN-Rqro